# Error installing OAuth on CentOS 6.0

Tags: centos6, installation, oauth

I'm not sure what to do here cause I'm getting the same type of error overall as i try to install oAuth on this cloud slice.  I'm not sure what to do but I would think that I need to update or reinstall the ? yum ? or um.. well here is what I have done listed below..

I first try to run pecl install Phar . but `make` error..

```
[root@pleasures ~]# pecl install Phar
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
WARNING: "pear/bz2" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://php.net/bzip2/ext/bz2"
Did not download optional dependencies: pecl/bz2, pecl/hash, use --alldeps to download automatically
downloading phar-2.0.0.tgz ...
Starting to download phar-2.0.0.tgz (450,821 bytes)
............................................................................................done: 450,821 bytes
28 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootCbNGKf/phar-2.0.0
running: /var/tmp/phar/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for phar archive support... yes, shared
checking for phar openssl support... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootCbNGKf/phar-2.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/phar -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootCbNGKf/phar-2.0.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootCbNGKf/phar-2.0.0/main -I/var/tmp/phar -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/phar/util.c -o util.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/phar -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootCbNGKf/phar-2.0.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootCbNGKf/phar-2.0.0/main -I/var/tmp/phar -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/phar/util.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/util.o
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_array.h:26,
                 from /var/tmp/phar/phar_internal.h:59,
                 from /var/tmp/phar/util.c:23:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_array.h:26,
                 from /var/tmp/phar/phar_internal.h:59,
                 from /var/tmp/phar/util.c:23:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âpcreâ
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:30:25: error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:31:26: error: openssl/x509.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:32:28: error: openssl/x509v3.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:33:28: error: openssl/crypto.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:34:25: error: openssl/pem.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:35:25: error: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:36:26: error: openssl/conf.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:37:26: error: openssl/rand.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:38:25: error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:39:28: error: openssl/pkcs12.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/phar/util.c: In function âphar_verify_signatureâ:
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1792: error: âBIOâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1792: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1792: error: for each function it appears in.)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1792: error: âinâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1793: error: âEVP_PKEYâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1793: error: âkeyâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1794: error: âEVP_MDâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1794: error: âmdtypeâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1794: error: expected expression before â)â token
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1795: error: âEVP_MD_CTXâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1795: error: expected â;â before âmd_ctxâ
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:1872: error: âmd_ctxâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c: In function âphar_create_signatureâ:
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2117: error: âBIOâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2117: error: âinâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2118: error: âEVP_PKEYâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2118: error: âkeyâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2119: error: âEVP_MDâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2119: error: âmdtypeâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2119: error: expected expression before â)â token
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2120: error: âEVP_MD_CTXâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2120: error: expected â;â before âmd_ctxâ
/var/tmp/phar/util.c:2143: error: âmd_ctxâ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [util.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

then run pecl install oauth

```
[root@pleasures ~]# pecl install oauth
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading oauth-1.2.3.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.2.3.tgz (45,531 bytes)
.............done: 45,531 bytes
6 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootSN967P/oauth-1.2.3
running: /var/tmp/oauth/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for oauth support... yes, shared
checking for cURL in default path... found in /usr
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootSN967P/oauth-1.2.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootSN967P/oauth-1.2.3/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootSN967P/oauth-1.2.3/main -I/var/tmp/oauth -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -g   -c /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c -o oauth.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootSN967P/oauth-1.2.3/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootSN967P/oauth-1.2.3/main -I/var/tmp/oauth -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -g -c /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oauth.o
In file included from /var/tmp/oauth/php_oauth.h:47,
                 from /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c:14:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /var/tmp/oauth/php_oauth.h:47,
                 from /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c:14:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âpcreâ
make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to compile this yourself instead of just doing:

```
yum install php-pecl-oauth
```

The package can be found in the [remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/), which I recommend for most people deploying PHP/MySQL based web applications on CentOS.

Comment: well to anwser your question, cause I'm learning still :D .. but spot on. thank you for the quick response.